# rails ajax form submission issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

**UPDATED...**

i am having trouble with my ajax form submissions. not sure if its a routing issue, or possibly a UJS issue. (using jquery 1.6.1 and the most recent jquery-ujs)

this is the generated html for the create action form

```
<form method="post" id="new_product_pressing" data-remote="true" class="simple_form product_pressing" action="/products/my_product_id/product_pressings" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8">
  <input type="hidden" value="blablablatokenblablabla" name="authenticity_token">
  <label for="product_pressing_total_pressed">Total pressed</label>
  <input type="text" size="5" required="required" name="product_pressing[total_pressed]" id="product_pressing_total_pressed" 
  <input type="submit" value="Create Pressing" name="commit" id="product_pressing_submit">
</form>
```

the update action form is valid as well, but probably redundant to post

my routes are:

```
resources :products, :shallow => true do
  resources :product_pressings, :as => :pressings, :only => [:create, :update]
end

product_pressings POST /products/:product_id/product_pressings(.:format)  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"product_pressings"}
pressing          PUT  /product_pressings/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"update", :controller=>"product_pressings"}
```

for the create action... the log shows:

```
Started POST "/products/product-057/product_pressings" for 127.0.0.1 at...
Processing by ProductPressingsController#create as JS
Parameters: {"product_id"=>"my_product_id"}
```

if i remove remote true, the `"product_pressing"=>{}` parameters get passed, but not with :remote => true.

for update...

```
Started POST "/product_pressings/4e01ad24e1607cc46100008e" for 127.0.0.1 at...
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/product_pressings/4e01ad24e1607cc46100008e"):
```

throws a routing error, even though its shows the exact url and method as without remote => true.  this was working, and im not sure when it stopped, but i don't understand what could cause this behavior.

Comment: Is this a create or an update action? Does it work the same in both new/edit forms?

Comment: I can't see any csrf token...

Answer (score 0):

found the problem.  my fault.  i had extended jquery with plugins named $.param and $.params.  that was conflicting with jquery ujs apparently.  it wasn't easy to track down, but just had to rename it. problem solved.